# Change ActiveMQ broker JMX port 1099 in Spring Boot JMS

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I use Spring Boot with embedded Active-MQ as JMS-Provider and it works quite well but: I need to run multiple instances on one host. When I start the second instance I get the following error:

```
    2018-12-17 17:23:25.498  WARN 11042 --- [JMX connector] o.a.a.broker.jmx.ManagementContext       : Failed to start JMX connector Cannot bind to URL [rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi]: javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException: jmxrmi [Root exception is java.rmi.AlreadyBoundException: jmxrmi]. Will restart management to re-create JMX connector, trying to remedy this issue.
```

This is of course because port 1099 is already used by the first instance. Sadly I really dont find a way to change this port using any spring.activemq.* property or an instance of ActiveMQConnectionFactoryCustomizer. Can anyone help me?

Best regards, Dominic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you even need jmxrmi?
You can disable it with (at least for one of your instances):

```
org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.createConnector=false
```

(in application.properties or with VM argument -Dorg.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.createConnector=false)